# Creating a numpy array with dimension, mean, and variance as parameters?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

How do I create a numpy array with the dimensions, mean, and variance as parameters? I see there is a `numpy.random.randn` function which allows the user to specify dimensions, but that function assumes a mean of 0 and variance of 1.

I am okay with the mean 0 part, but I want to be able to specify a variance each time I am creating a new numpy array.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy-random-normal). For example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.50, size=(500, 500))

print(arr.mean())  # 0.9995707343806642
print(arr.std())   # 0.5010967322495354
```

Here `loc` represents the mean and `scale` the standard deviation, i.e. the square root of variance.

Of course, you are *drawing samples* from a distribution, so you will not have a mean of 1.0 or a standard deviation of 0.50, unless you have a very large array.

Answer (score 3):

From the numpy documentation ([`numpy.random.randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)):

For random samples from [image: N(\mu, \sigma^2)], when mu is the mean and sigma is the variance (see [Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)), use:

```
sigma * np.random.randn(d0, d1, ..., dn) + mu
```

When `(d0, d1, ..., dn)` is the shape of the generated array.

Comment: Awesome, seems that I missed that!

Comment: mu is the mean and sigma is the variance.